# pandas range_date slows down function extremly

Tags: python, pandas

I have given a sample data set and want to choose multiple samples from the original sample data set, e.g 1000 sample block each consisting of 500 data points from the original sample data. I've wrote this little function in python:

```
import timeit
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
sample_data = np.random.randn(10000, 15)
index = pd.date_range("20000101", periods=10000, freq='B')
sample_data_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data, index=index)
def f(n, sample_data_df, f):
    s = (1+sample_data_df).resample(f, axis=0)
    r = s.prod()-1
    out = r.sample(n, replace=True)
    # out_index = pd.date_range(start=sample_data_df.index[0],
    #                              periods=len(out.index),
    #                              freq=f)
    # out.index = output_index
    return out


start_time = timeit.default_timer()
N = 1000
a = [f(500, sample_data_df, 'BM') for i in range(N)]
elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
print(elapsed)
```

If I run this code it takes 35.8964748383 seconds. However, I would like to have an index attached to each of the blocks I would uncomment the lines in the function, i.e.

```
def f(n, sample_data_df, f):
        s = (1+sample_data_df).resample(f, axis=0)
        r = s.prod()-1
        out = r.sample(n, replace=True)
        out_index = pd.date_range(start=sample_data_df.index[0],
                                  periods=len(out.index),
                                  freq=f)
        out.index = output_index
        return out
```

Now the function takes **72.2418179512**. This is insane. How can I speed up this if it would be required to have such an index in each output? I'm aware of generating once the index and attach it afterwards to each output. However, I would like to use the function in other cases as well so that it would be much appreciated if the assignment of the indexing is done within the function.

Moreover, besides the indexing is there other sources to improve the speed? Because even without indexing 35.8964748383 is a long time.

Comment: Do you need to resample within the function?

Comment: @djk47463 Yes, the function is actually a method of a class which purpose is to resample. What I was thinking is to write a decorator which adds the indexing. Is that pythonic? Do you know why indexing in pandas is so slow? For a beginner like me :) indexing sounds like a pretty cheap thing to do. Is date types not handled efficiently in pandas?

Comment: resampling/date ranges with a frequency larger than a Day is a known perf issue in pandas, see linked issue, PRs to help are welcome! https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16463

Comment: see also https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17914

Comment: @chrisb many thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited:

- Added timings for creating new date index
- Added cached function to create new index

The problem is not so much the speed of the resampling or the indexing, if we look at the timing:

```
%timeit (1+sample_data_df).resample('BM', axis=0).prod()-1
21.7 ms ± 170 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit pd.date_range(start="20000101", periods=500, freq='BM')
21.4 ms ± 272 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

22 ms don't seem to bad for me considering we are doing a resampling and reduction on 150'000 elements.

Your problem comes from doing it 1000, which, in your case is not necessary(because you are doing the exact same thing).
What you can do, if you want to keep the resampling in the function, is caching the result of the resampling. Unfortunately the standard way to cache the result of a function (lru_cache) is not able to handle mutable objects (like dfs, lists... ). So my solution for this is to wrap the resampling in a function that creates the hash and call the actual function with the hash as a parameter:

```
from functools import lru_cache
class Sampler():
  def __init__(self, df):
    self.df = df

  def get_resampled_sample(self, n, freq):
    resampled = self._wraper_resample_prod(freq)
    return resampled.sample(n, replace=True)

  def _wraper_resample_prod(self, freq):
    hash_df = hash(self.df.values.tobytes())
    return self._resample_prod(hash_df, freq)

  @lru_cache(maxsize=1)  
  def _resample_prod(self, hash_df, freq):
    return (self.df+1).resample(freq, axis=0).prod()-1
```

Now the result of the resampling is cached as long as the hash of the values of the df are not changed. And this means we can sample much faster.

```
%timeit [sampler.get_resampled_sample(500, 'BM') for i in range(1000)]
881 ms ± 10.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

You can do the same thing with the index, but here you don't need to create a custom hash because all parameters for pd.date_range are immutable objects.

```
class Sampler():
  def __init__(self, df):
    self.df = df

  def update_df(self, df):
    self.df = df

  def get_resampled_sample(self, n, freq):
    resampled = self._wraper_resample_prod(freq)
    df = resampled.sample(n, replace=True)
    df.index = self._create_date_range(self.df.index[0], n, freq)
    return df

  def _wraper_resample_prod(self, freq):
    hash_df = hash(self.df.values.tobytes())
    return self._resample_prod(hash_df, freq)

  @lru_cache(maxsize=1)  
  def _resample_prod(self, hash_df, freq):
    return (self.df+1).resample(freq, axis=0).prod()-1

  @lru_cache(maxsize=1)
  def _create_date_range(self, start, periods, freq):
    return pd.date_range(start=start, periods=periods, freq=freq)
```

Timings:

```
%timeit [sampler.get_resampled_sample(500, 'BM') for i in range(1000)]
1.11 s ± 43.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer. I do agree this will efficiently speed up things. I've never used caching before so many thanks for the hint in the right direction. While you provide a overall optimization I'm still struggling to understand why indexing vs no indexing makes such a big difference (time-wise). I will keep the bounty open to see if someone else might provide another answer.

Comment: @math I added a cached function to create the new date index. The same argument is valid here, too. Creating the index is not really slow (It takes around 20 ms on my pc) but doing it a 1000 times in your list comprehension just adds up.

Comment: Many thanks for the added piece. would it be cleaner to have a decorator for the indexing (no caching). The plain function does not do indexing and an the decorated one would do it?

Comment: @math I'm not really an expert on this but i don't think that this is a problem you would use a decorator for. I think it would be much more practical to have a keyword argument in the function that controls if the sampled df gets reindexed.